# JQuery validate plugin, ajax submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am using JQuery validate on two fields.  I do all my validation and display messages if validation fails.  I then have my submit handler which is using Ajax

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
         $.ajax({
            type: $(form).attr('method'),
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            dataType : 'json'
        })
        .done(function (response) {
            if (response.success == 'success') {               
                alert('success');                       
            } else {
                alert('fail');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

My problem is that both fields are not required, only one or the other (or both). I have handled this no problem.  However, the submitted data will be sent to my PHP file using Ajax.  In this PHP, I check to see what fields have data e.g.

```
if (isset($_POST["mobileNumber"] && !empty($_POST["mobileNumber"])){
    var_dump("WORKING");
}
```

I then need to check the input against a web service API.  If I do this seperately, it is not a problem.  However, if both inputs are entered into the form, I then need to make 2 API calls to 2 different APIs (each input uses a different API), and then return the response for both back to .done.  Once again, if only one input is provided, I dont see a problem.  The thing I am wondering about is if both inputs are provided, and how I can return both response?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you send both the responses of the API calls back in one response?

```
$response = array();

if (isset($_POST["mobileNumber"] && !empty($_POST["mobileNumber"])){
    $response['mobileNumberResponse'] = array('success'=>true,'data'=>array());
}

if (isset($_POST["secondParameter"] && !empty($_POST["secondParameter"])){
    $response['secondParameter'] = array('success'=>true,'data'=>array());
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Or something similar. If this isn't an option send two ajax's requests if both parameters are present.